# Highcharts- Creating a dynamic x-axis to maintain bar spacing with less data points but maintain x-axis "width"

Tags: highcharts, html5-canvas, opentext, clientscript

I'm looking for a solution to add to my clientscript in actuate opentext studio. In the first image I have the columns of the grid lining up with the table bars; this is for a 28 day period. I need a similar display when having less data points- basically maintaining the same column spacing pattern in the graph given less data points. Currently the second image shows what happens when I use a parameter of 14 days instead of 28 days. The grid is fine, but I need it to line of similarly to the first example.

Example 1:
[Correct Line up of Grid and Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtyPB.png)

Example 2: [Incorrect widening of the spacing in Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytq30.png)

Comment: Hi @Amanda Sackett, Do you want to show empty space, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4817/ ?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, yes I do; exactly like that. Although I won't be defining data points like in your example. It'll be a cleanscript I'm adding into actuate/optext designer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thanks @ppotaczek. Your comment put me on the right track! Very new to this but that helped a lot. It sets the "empty" values as having a 'null' label instead of being empty/blank so that's something I'll have to workout but thanks!

Below code will set your bar widths, and return blank values/max set around your parameters. My max was 28 so I subtracted by one to get the correct output.

> beforeGeneration: function(options)
>
> { options.xAxis.max = 27
>
> //You can change options here.    options.plotOptions = {    series: {
>
> pointWidth: 25, //size of column    pointPadding: 0.25, //size of
>
> padding between each bar    groupPadding: 0 //padding between each
>
> value groups in x axis    }    };    },